# Call entire list, 2000 items at a time?

Tags: 2007, list, list-view, performance

If I need to store say 10,000 items in a list, but want to call them sequentially 2000 items at a time, what is the best method for doing that? I assume it's similar to a paged call, but want to execute this the right way.

This is in SharePoint 2007

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [built-in SPQuery paging mechanism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitemcollectionposition%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

```
SPWeb oWebsite = SPContext.Current.Web;
SPList oList = oWebsite.Lists["Announcements"];

SPQuery oQuery = new SPQuery();
oQuery.RowLimit = 2000;
oQuery.Query = "<OrderBy Override=\"TRUE\">" + 
    "<FieldRef Name=\"FileLeafRef\" /></OrderBy>";

int intIndex = 1;

do
{
    Response.Write("<BR>Page: " + intIndex + "<BR>");
    SPListItemCollection collListItems = oList.GetItems(oQuery);

    foreach (SPListItem oListItem in collListItems)
    {
        Response.Write(SPEncode.HtmlEncode(oListItem["Title"].ToString()) +
        "<BR>");
    }

    oQuery.ListItemCollectionPosition =
        collListItems.ListItemCollectionPosition;
    intIndex++;
} while (oQuery.ListItemCollectionPosition != null);
```

Comment: You sir, are a gentleman and a scholar.

Comment: Nope, I just know how to Google :)